# Condición IF con una ruta ¿Se puede?

Tags: java, jsf

Mi duda es si se podría hacer algo así:

```
if (../preprogrammed.xhtml == true) {
...
}
```

Es que tengo un problema con una cosa que estoy haciendo, y si esto se puede hacer me resultaría más fácil.
Sería una url.
Es decir, entro en www.marca.com/betis.html, pues quiero una condición que sea: if(../betis.html) { ... }

Comment: si que se puede, mira esta respuesta que es lo que buscas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816676/7856247 con esa respuesta compruebas si existe el fichero

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Perdón, no me expliqué bien, me refiero a una url sin terminar, es decir, entro en www.marca.com/betis.html, pues quiero una condición que sea: if(../betis.html) { ... }

Comment: lo que quieres es ccomprobar si existe una parte de una URL? Mmmmm... no se como se podría hacer eso pero me suena raro, creo que tendrás ue evaluar la ruta completa

Comment: Si efectivamente, quiero comprobar el último archivo de la url. @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: sin darle la ruta completa, intentar ver si existe una parte sin ser de tu propio servidor... lo veo difícil que se pueda lograr, teines que indicar donde vas a buscar ese fichero...

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano O sabes como puedo hacer lo siguiente? Tengo 2 archivos xhtml, como compruebo desde el bean en cual estoy

Comment: Falta explicación y detalles en tu pregunta , incluir algo mas de codigo, de donde obtienes la url? Siempre puedes tratarla como String y usar sus metodos para comparar la url con la cadena de texto que quieras. Comprobar que una direccion URL existe, se hace comprobando que se conecta a dicha url